# Cannot get function declaration to work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot get this array function to work. I have several `div` elements with `id="cell1"`, `"cell2`, `cell3`...

What is wrong about this function declaration? I am getting the following error:

> Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var cell = [];
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 16; i = i + 1) {
    cell[i] = document.getElementById('cell' + i);
}
cell.onclick = function () {
    this.style.background = "red";
};
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined

Comment: I can't see how you'd even get the error you describe, not from that code.

Comment: The onclick handler is set to an Array, it will not ever fire. Not reproduceable.

Comment: That isn't a function declaration, it's assignment of a [*function expression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
cell.onclick = function...
```

adds an `onclick` property to the *array*, not to any of its elements. So it won't (for example) get called by a cell getting clicked.

It will work if you attach it to the elements themselves:

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i = i + 1) {
  cell[i] = document.getElementById('cell' + i);
  cell[i].onclick = function () {
    this.style.background = "red";
  };    
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/nesegixu/1)

...although that creates a lot more functions than you need; a single handler can deal with all of them:

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i = i + 1) {
  cell[i] = document.getElementById('cell' + i);
  cell[i].onclick = handleClick;    
}

function handleClick() {
  this.style.background = "red";
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/nesegixu/2)

---

Side note: Be sure that you're running this code *after* the elements already exist. The best practices way to ensure that is simply to put your script at the very bottom of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so that all elements defined by the HTML above the script have been created.

---

Side note 2: Arrays in JavaScript start with index `0`, so your `cell` array will have an empty element at index `0`. It doesn't do any harm, but I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, he should call the script when the these document elements are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) {
    cell[i] = document.getElementById('cell' + i);
    cell[i].onclick = function () {
        this.style.background = "red";
    };
}
```

1. Change `i = 1` to `i = 0`, because first object in array has index 0, in your case you are accessing all objects *except* first.
2. `cell` is array, because you declared it as such: `var cell = [];`. Array doesn't handle `onclick` events, but its objects do (in your case).
3. You are looping through elements of array, so we put

   ```
   cell.onclick = function () {
       this.style.background = "red";
   };
   ```

   in loop. But we remember that array doesn't handle `onclick` events, so we add `[i]` - it adds same  `on click` for all elements in this array.

Answer (score 1):

**This is now moot with the OP's latest edit.**

<strike>Without pulling apart the rest of the code, this is the immediate issue:</strike>

```
cell.onclick = function () {...
```

<strike>You're trying to bind something to a non-existent event, i.e. `onclick` on an array, not an element in the page. You need to bind against a specific index, i.e.:</strike>

```
cell[i].onclick = function () {...
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
cell.onclick = function () {
this.style.background = "red";
};
```

Is supposed to be this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
    cell[i].onclick = function(){
      //do your click action...
    }
}
```

The way you are doing, you are attaching the click event to the array, instead you need to attach to the div objects inside the array.